# Unable to add azure key vault backed secret scope in community databricks edition

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-keyvault, databricks-community-edition

I am Trying to add secret scope (Azure key vault backed) in Databricks Community version but giving me below error when I check its response it is saying ENDPOINT NOT FOUND.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Secrets aren't supported on Databricks community edition. The web UI is just left from the full version.

P.S. But if you are on Azure, you can freely create a new workspace for your work - if you don't run workloads 24x7 or with big clusters, it won't cost you too much (if you don't run anything, you pay just for data stored on DBFS).